# How to read a CSV in Python which is 99% UTF-8 encoded

Tags: python, csv, unicode, character-encoding, decoding

I have large CSV files (>100.000 rows, 50 columns) which are "mainly" UTF-8 encoded.

On one of them, let's call it `file.csv` I run

```
$ chardetect file.csv
file.csv: utf-8 with confidence 0.99
```

However when I read the file in Python with a `csv.DictReader` instance I get a unicode error with a stack trace like:

```
  File "/path/to/python3.8/csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "/path/to//python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 7801: invalid start byte
```

I tried other encodings, but the file is for sure "mainly" UTF-8, just with a few problems. How can I still read this file as a CSV in Python?

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file with a more forgiving `errors` handling strategy…?

Comment: `b'twice\xadbaked'.decode('utf8', errors='replace')` -> `'twice�baked'`.  `errors='strict'` (the default) will reproduce your error.  FYI, `b'\xad'` decodes to `SOFT HYPHEN` in some common legacy encodings.  It probably got inserted erroneously in your data.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the comment! `errors='replace'` does the trick in my case.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the little detail with `SOFT HYPHEN`. That's exactly what it is. MS Excel on Windows might have added it in on CSV export.